# Join table in MySQL with "WHERE field < NUM"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have two tables in my DB that I need to join. The first one if `words`, second one `votes`. Table `words` contains english words, and the table `votes` is for votes for translations of words. Each such vote has field "weight". When common users are voting the new entrie creates with weight = 1, if admin — weight = 10.

I need to select all the words that have no admin's vote (with a single query).

Here is a simplified version of the query I'm trying to do

```
SELECT w.* FROM words AS w
LEFT JOIN votes AS v ON w.word = v.word
WHERE v.weight < 10 // help me out here
```

Let's say the table with votes has such entries.

```
[id]  [word]   [translation]   [weight]
1     you      ты              1
2     you      вы              10
3     you      ваши            1
4     hello    привет          1
5     hello    привет          1
```

So the word "you" should not be selected because it has a vote of admin.

Comment: Is that you are looking for `WHERE v.weight < 10 AND word <>'you'` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a comparison in the `where` clause:

```
SELECT w.*
FROM words w
WHERE not exists (select 1 from votes v where v.word = w.word and v.weight = 10);
```

That is, select all words where there doesn't exist a record with an admin vote.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 alternatives which mostly differ in readability and performance depending on your database setup and how MySQL decides to interpret the query in your database environment.

Classic subquery:

```
SELECT  w.*
FROM    words w
WHERE   NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT  1
            FROM    votes v
            WHERE   v.word = w.word
            AND     v.weight = 10
        )
```

IN() subquery:

```
SELECT  w.*
FROM    words w
WHERE   w.word NOT IN(
            SELECT  v.word
            FROM    votes v
            WHERE   v.weight = 10
        )
```

LEFT JOIN with IS NULL:

```
SELECT    w.*
FROM      words w
LEFT JOIN votes v
ON        (   v.word = w.word
          AND v.weight = 10
          )
WHERE     v.weight IS NULL
```

Unless I made a typo, all those should give identical result but with different performance characteristics, so I recommend you try them all out and check which performs best for your situation.

Comment: Sucks... I have tryed all the ways you suggested but they are all too heavy, queries takes more than 30 seconds so my apache returns timeout error. Maybe that's because my tables are too huge :(

Comment: Then you most likely don't have an index on votes.word and votes.weight. Make sure your indices are set properly and use "EXPLAIN SELECT ..." to check if it's using those indices. We have tables with tens of millions of entries and can perform such queries in less than a second.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM votes
WHERE max(weight)=1
GROUP BY word
```

Comment: WHERE takes place before grouping, so WHERE MAX(weight) doesn't work. You have to use HAVING instead.